# Is there any way to rearrange this kind of data?

Tags: r, dataframe, structure

Each ID has a gender and age, and function data. I was wondering how I should get a data set in which I can analyze.

```
------------------------
original data form is:
ID gender age fun
1 M 10 2.5
1 M 10 2.4
1 M 10 3.3
1 M 10 5.5
1 M 10 2.2
2 F 11 4.4
2 F 11 3.3
2 F 11 2.2
2 F 11 1.1
2 F 11 3.3


I want a from of data like:
ID gender age fun
1 M 10 2.5 2.4 3.3 5.5 2.2
2 F 11 4.4 3.3 2.2 1.1 3.3

------------------------
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(N = 1:n()) %>%
  spread(N, fun) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 2 x 8
#      ID gender   age   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
#   <int> <chr>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 M         10   2.5   2.4   3.3   5.5   2.2
# 2     2 F         11   4.4   3.3   2.2   1.1   3.3
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID gender age fun
1 M 10 2.5
1 M 10 2.4
1 M 10 3.3
1 M 10 5.5
1 M 10 2.2
2 F 11 4.4
2 F 11 3.3
2 F 11 2.2
2 F 11 1.1
2 F 11 3.3",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @akrun I thought `1:n()` and `row_number` both work.